# fully-typed generic promise typings

Tags: typescript

In [Announcing Typescript 1.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-typescript-1-0rc.aspx) it mentions "fully-typed generic promise typings. That's Greek to me.

Can someone give me an explanation of this and an example of it's use as it applies to Typescript 1.0?

Comment: It just means that there are relaxations to the generic typing rules such that it is now easier to declare promise-like types.  I am perplexed about that too. With 0.9.5, I have been able to declare promise types in exactly the same way as they show in the document. Sadly the TypeScript team does not give more info on what has been enhanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is as mentioned in the example. The following would fail, i.e. TS could not compile an implementation of a promise library (and it should compile):

```
interface Promise<Value> {
    result: Value;

    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => Promise<T2>): Promise<T2>;
    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => T2): Promise<T2>;
}

class PromiseImpl<Value> implements Promise<Value> {

    result: Value;

    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => Promise<T2>): Promise<T2>;
    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => T2): Promise<T2>;
    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => any): Promise<T2> {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

The issue is different from being able to *define*. e.g. the following would compile (an interface definition):

```
interface Promise<Value> {
    result: Value;

    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => Promise<T2>): Promise<T2>;    
}

interface PromiseImpl<Value> extends Promise<Value> {

    result: Value;

    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => Promise<T2>): Promise<T2>;
    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => T2): Promise<T2>;
    then<T2>(f: (v: Value) => any): Promise<T2>;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the <Value> type parameter means?